# Automatic/dynamic multiprocessing python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a Random Forest, and using K-fold validation I'm trying to find optimal values for depth lenght and some other parameters.
I am running a QuadCore CPU thus I am trying to figure out, how i can iterate over say `max_depth = range(50,101)`, such that when one of the cores is done fitting its forest with its `max_depth` it automatically takes the next `max_depth` in the list.
Or is it better splitting `max_depth` in 4 equal sizes and just make 4 processes manually?

Comment: What Machine Learning library are you using, Jakob? scikit-learn lets you enjoy some parallel processing if you specify `n_jobs` when calling `RandomForestClassifier()`or `RandomForestRegressor()`

Comment: Ooh... it is actually sklearn! I did not know that, thanks! But also it was more a general question, nice to know though :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best solution would be using queues and manual process-creation. That way, you have full control over the processes.

1. Create your function that does the Random forest after getting its `max_depth` from an input queue. Push the result in an output queue.
2. You put all your `max_depth`values in the input queue
3. You create a number of processes that best fit your architecture. Typically, 8 processes for 4 cores (with Hyperthreading) is a goot starting point
4. Start the processes.

After starting the processes each one will take one argument from the input queue and does your RandomForest. After one process has finished, it puts the result in another queue and retrieves another argument from the input queue. Using the queue, you don't have to care which process is finishing first etc. as the queues are thread-safe, so that only one process can access them. Any other will wait for access. You also wouldn't have to worry what your best split of the `max_depth`-list is. As soon as one process is finished it automatically gets a new value for the calculation. If nothing is in the queue, it stops.

I usually prefer this type of multiprocessing over `Pool` as I have a bit more control. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42625054/4141279) is a small example.