# Function that multiprocesses another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory, concurrent.futures

I'm performing analyses of time-series of simulations. Basically, it's doing the same tasks for every time steps. As there is a very high number of time steps, and as the analyze of each of them is independant, I wanted to create a function that can multiprocess another function. The latter will have arguments, and return a result.

Using a shared dictionnary and the lib concurrent.futures, I managed to write this :

```
import concurrent.futures as Cfut
def multiprocess_loop_grouped(function, param_list, group_size, Nworkers, *args):
    # function : function that is running in parallel
    # param_list : list of items
    # group_size : size of the groups
    # Nworkers : number of group/items running in the same time
    # **param_fixed : passing parameters

    manager = mlp.Manager()
    dic = manager.dict()
    executor = Cfut.ProcessPoolExecutor(Nworkers)

    futures = [executor.submit(function, param, dic, *args)
           for param in grouper(param_list, group_size)]

    Cfut.wait(futures)
    return [dic[i] for i in sorted(dic.keys())]
```

Typically, I can use it like this :

```
def read_file(files, dictionnary):
    for file in files:
        i = int(file[4:9])
        #print(str(i))
        if 'bz2' in file:
            os.system('bunzip2 ' + file)
            file = file[:-4]
        dictionnary[i] = np.loadtxt(file)
        os.system('bzip2 ' + file)

Map = np.array(multiprocess_loop_grouped(read_file, list_alti, Group_size, N_thread))
```

or like this :

```
def autocorr(x):
    result = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')
    return result[result.size//2:]

def find_lambda_finger(indexes, dic, Deviation):
    for i in indexes :
        #print(str(i))
        # Beach = Deviation[i,:] - np.mean(Deviation[i,:])
        dic[i] = Anls.find_first_max(autocorr(Deviation[i,:]), valmax = True)

args = [Deviation]
Temp = Rescal.multiprocess_loop_grouped(find_lambda_finger, range(Nalti), Group_size, N_thread, *args)
```

Basically, it is working. But it is not working well. Sometimes it crashes. Sometimes it actually launches a number of python processes equal to Nworkers, and sometimes there is only 2 or 3 of them running at a time while I specified `Nworkers = 15`.

For example, a classic error I obtain is described in the following topic I raised : [Calling matplotlib AFTER multiprocessing sometimes results in error : main thread not in main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045307/calling-matplotlib-after-multiprocessing-sometimes-results-in-error-main-threa)

What is the more Pythonic way to achieve what I want ? How can I improve the control this function ? How can I control more the number of running python process ?

Comment: Is the function you want to multi-process always the same? Or do you need the prototype `multiprocess_loop_grouped` to work with arbitrary functions? What data do you need for the processes? Just the time step? Or additional stuff?

Comment: As you can see in the two example of use I've put ate the end of the main message, I'd like it to work with arbitrary functions as I have multiple steps in the analysis of the data. Usually, I have to run step 2 over the 1000 sets of data, then step 3 over the 1000 sets of data, and then step 4 over the 1000 outputs of step 2 and 3. The data are stored in a numpy array over which I can either loop/multiprocess. For example, 'Deviation' in the second example I gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic concepts for Python multi-processing is using queues. It works quite well when you have an input list that can be iterated and which does not need to be altered by the sub-processes. It also gives you a good control over all the processes, because you spawn the number you want, you can run them idle or stop them.

It is also a lot easier to debug. Sharing data explicitly is usually an approach that is much more difficult to setup correctly.

Queues can hold anything as they are iterables by definition. So you can fill them with filepath strings for reading files, non-iterable numbers for doing calculations or even images for drawing.

In your case a layout could look like that:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import itertools as it


def worker1(in_queue, out_queue):
    #holds when nothing is available, stops when 'STOP' is seen
    for a in iter(in_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        #do something
        out_queue.put({a: result}) #return your result linked to the input

def worker2(in_queue, out_queue):
    for a in iter(in_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        #do something differently
        out_queue.put({a: result}) //return your result linked to the input

def multiprocess_loop_grouped(function, param_list, group_size, Nworkers, *args):
    # your final result
    result = {}

    in_queue = mp.Queue()
    out_queue = mp.Queue()

    # fill your input
    for a in param_list:
        in_queue.put(a)
    # stop command at end of input
    for n in range(Nworkers):
        in_queue.put('STOP')

    # setup your worker process doing task as specified
    process = [mp.Process(target=function,
               args=(in_queue, out_queue), daemon=True) for x in range(Nworkers)]

    # run processes
    for p in process:
        p.start()

    # wait for processes to finish
    for p in process:
        p.join()

    # collect your results from the calculations
    for a in param_list:
        result.update(out_queue.get())

    return result

temp = multiprocess_loop_grouped(worker1, param_list, group_size, Nworkers, *args)
map = multiprocess_loop_grouped(worker2, param_list, group_size, Nworkers, *args)
```

It can be made a bit more dynamic when you are afraid that your queues will run out of memory. Than you need to fill and empty the queues while the processes are running. See this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42625054/4141279).

Final words: it is not more Pythonic as you requested. But it is easier to understand for a newbie ;-)

Comment: Thanks for these details. Before starting to work on Python multi processing features, I saw that there was two libs, `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocessing` and that I had to choose between the two of them. 
I already understood the concept of Queues, but I guessed that the `ProcessPoolExecutor` of `concurrent.futures` was managing all of this, better than I could do by writing the different steps using `multiprocessing` ?

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is AFAIK an easier interface for working parallel. It bundles the older `multiprocessing ` and `multithreading` into one module and adds some features. So it is not a bad choice. It is a good way to do simple multiprocessing if you don't want to care about details. And it is quite new, so I have no experience using it. I assume that `concurrent.futures` does all the same as I did manually. But in my code I know what's going on. The other is kind of black box which I usually don't like (I am scientist btw....). And I started with the `multiprocesssing`-module.